# Synonym request: "piracy-protection" and "piracy-prevention"

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

The two tags [piracy-protection](/questions/tagged/piracy-protection) and [piracy-prevention](/questions/tagged/piracy-prevention) appear to mean the same thing.
They ought to be merged; one should be a synonym of the other.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840473/what-is-the-current-status-of-Android-app-encryption)
has both tags at the time of this writing.

Comment: +1, though I don't think "protection" and "prevention" mean the same thing, but it could be just me since I'm no native english speaker.

Comment: You need to synonymize `ninja` with both those piracy tags.

Comment: isn't the subtle difference that protection is pro-active and prevention is re-active (or the other way around?)?!

Comment: @DamienPirsy "Prevention" and "protection" indeed mean completely different things, but "Piracy protection" and "Piracy prevention" mean the same. This is because, implicitly, those short terms respectively mean "Protection *against* piracy" and "Prevention *of* piracy" - and *those* are effectively exactly the same thing.